# Can't calculate values

Tags: php

```
$invoiceTotal = $settings['Setting']['currency'] . $thisInvoice['Invoice']['invoice_total'];

$bedrag = $settings['Setting']['currency'] . number_format($thisInvoice['Payment']['0']['amount'], 2, '.', ',');

$openbedrag = $invoiceTotal - $bedrag;

//$invoiceTotal = 2 
//$bedrag = 1
```

Why is `$openbedrag = $invoiceTotal - $bedrag;` not working ?

It is a simple calculation, why it doesn't calculate this variables ?

It outputs 0 -_-'

**UPDATE PROBLEM FIXED**

```
$invoiceTotal = $settings['Setting']['currency'].$thisInvoice['Invoice']['invoice_total'];
$bedrag = $settings['Setting']['currency'].number_format($thisInvoice['Payment']['0']['amount'], 2, '.', ',');
$openbedrag2 = $thisInvoice['Invoice']['invoice_total'] - $thisInvoice['Payment']['0']['amount'];
$openbedrag = $settings['Setting']['currency'].$openbedrag2;
```

Currency sets €

Comment: You can't do arithmetic when the number begins with a currency symbol.

Comment: what $settings['Setting']['currency'] this part containing? value or symbol?

Comment: @ripa It presumably contains a currency symbol, like `$` for US dollars or `£` for British pounds.

Comment: @Barmar Yes Barmer. I also posted my answer. please check it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do arithmetic with the original numbers, not the formatted ones.

```
$openbedrag = $thisInvoice['Invoice']['invoice_total'] - $thisInvoice['Payment']['0']['amount'];
```

Comment: THANKS, stupid of me. Forgot about the `$settings['Setting']['currency']` before the numbers -.-'

Answer (score 0):

convert into integers:-

```
$openbedrag = ($invoiceTotal * 1.0) - ($bedrag * 1.0);
```

Comment: PHP automatically converts strings to integers when you use arithmetic operators on them.

Comment: @user3078542: please make sure, your currency values does't have currency symbols

Comment: @Barmar you are right - I was considering might be some problem with conversion.

Answer (score 0):

if **$settings['Setting']['currency']** this containing symbol , then avoid using **$settings['Setting']['currency']** in Your calculation time. so Your calculation would be like below:-

```
$invoiceTotal =  $thisInvoice['Invoice']['invoice_total'];

$bedrag =  $thisInvoice['Payment']['0']['amount'];

$openbedrag = $invoiceTotal - $bedrag;

$openbedrag =  $settings['Setting']['currency'].number_format($openbedrag, 2, '.', ',');
```

**NOTE:- also don't use number_format in Your calculation time. use it ate display time means after the calculation in final output.**